# assignment within an echo statement

Tags: php, html

In my PHP file, I have an echo statement, that outputs some HTML, within which i want to do some assignment based on onclick event.

```
echo "<td style='padding:10px; text-align:left;'> <a target='_blank' href='stat.php'  onclick='".  $_SESSION['dakno'] = $r[$j]; ."' >".$r[$j]."</a></td>";
```

I have tried a lot of combinations, but still getting syntax error because of the onclick section.

```
echo "<td style='padding:10px; text-align:left;'> <a target='_blank' href='stat.php'  onclick='"<?php  $_SESSION['dakno'] = $r[$j]; ?> "' >".$r[$j]."</a></td>";
```

EDITS:

I am an output field in a table to be a hyperlink. On clicking the link, the value of the clicked item is passed to another PHP file using a SESSION variable.

```
$sno = 1;
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){

                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td style='padding:10px; text-align:left;'>".$sno."</td>"; $sno++;
                            for( $j=1; $j<6; $j++){
                                if($j == 1){
                                echo "<td style='padding:10px; text-align:left;'> <a target='_blank' href='stat.php'  onclick='".  $_SESSION['dakno'] = $r[$j]; ."' >".$r[$j]."</a></td>";


                                continue;
                                }
                                else
                                echo "<td style='padding:10px; text-align:left;'>".$r[$j]."</td>";

                            }
                            echo "</tr>";

                }
```

Please, help me to remove the syntax error I am making.

Comment: tried using esacpe characters as well.. \"
But nothing seems to work :/

Comment: Why are you using semi-colons before concatenation operator?

Comment: What's the point of this? You want this assignment in PHP to happen when the link is clicked? Then you're on a completely wrong path here.

Comment: onclick is use to call function. you can't assign something there

Comment: but we normally do echo values in HTML code.
Is there a possible way to do, what I am trying to achieve ?

Comment: @deceze is right. You can create a function which fires onclick, sends AJAX request and do the assignment.

Comment: What *are* you trying to achieve exactly? Your code makes no sense!

Comment: isn't there a solution without using AJAX. If I create the function in same PHP file and then call it onclick ?

Comment: made a few edits on question to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor

Comment: read that..obviously, you cant run a server side script on client side without ajax, but here I am working in a PHP file itself, so doesn't it change the scenario ?

Comment: @AkashGupta Then how do you expect to execute server-side code in a client-side event?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the question, I needed to pass the value to another PHP file when someone clicked the link. I did not want to use AJAX here as because I do not expect to update any content dynamically. After two hours of brainstorming, I solved my problem with an extremely basic solution.

```
$sno = 1;
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
echo "";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td style='padding:10px; text-align:left;'>".$sno."</td>"; $sno++;
                            for( $j=1; $j<6; $j++){
                                if($j == 1){

                                echo "<td style='padding:10px; text-align:left;'><form action='stat.php' method='POST'> <input type='hidden' name='dakno' value='".$r[$j]."' > </input> <button class='dakbutton' type='submit'>".$r[$j]."</button></form></td>";


                                continue;
                                }
                                else
                                echo "<td style='padding:10px; text-align:left;'>".$r[$j]."</td>";

                            }
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</form>";
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "<td style='padding:10px; text-align:left;'> <a target='_blank' href='stat.php'  onclick='" .
$_SESSION['dakno'] = $r[$j] .
    "' >" .
    $r[$j].
    "</a></td>";
```

remove `;` in `$_SESSION['dakno'] = $r[$j];`

Comment: on removing the ';', it simply runs likes normal PHP and doesn't execute on click event. Basically it executes every time without knowing if the event occurred or not.

Comment: I just want to solve the **syntax error** problem. I suggest to use AJAX to pass value to other php file

Comment: @Larry.Z Didn't downvote, but you should point it out in the comments.  That's not what the answer field is for.  It's for answering the question, fixing any errors present is an aside.

Comment: @Daedalus, Thanks, I will think about it next time :)